# JavaScript to PHP - POST encoding issue

Tags: php, javascript, post, encoding, utf-8

I'm attempting to send a string from client-side JavaScript to a back-end PHP script. The string contains special quotes like `’` and `“`.

When I look at the console in Chrome I can see that these are sent in the POST headers as they are. On the PHP side I then immediately `json_encode()` the `$_POST` array and send it back to see what its collected. The special characters now look like this `\u2019`. *This is for testing please note I would normally sanitize all post data.*

I wish to use UTF-8 but I'm not sure what I'm missing. My HTML includes:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

My PHP server has UTF-8 set as its default charset.

If I start saving such data to the database I start ending up with strings like this: `Ã¢ÂÂ` for `’`. However **this is not a database issue** the characters are already bad before going into the database. MySQL purely accentuates them.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I've noticed that if I return the string back to javascript without using `json_encode()` then it's in its original format with the special quotes (`’` and `“`) still.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` instead of what you have for the meta tag?

Comment: That's just the correct output, UTF-8 characters should be encoded like `\uXXXX` in JSON. @Jon: That's the same, only in HTML 5 syntax. BTW, don't sanitize your POST data, use the correct escaping/encoding when outputting/using the data.

Comment: It wasn't specified, so I assume XHTML or HTML 4.x ^^ But @MarcelKorpel is correct with that being correct return after a `json_encode`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange Characters in database text: Ã, Ã, ¢, â‚ €,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861358/strange-characters-in-database-text-a-a-a)

Comment: Your database problem seems more like an encoding issue. Do you use UTF-8 as collation?

Comment: See my answers for this duplicate:
[Strange Characters in database text: Ã, Ã, ¢, â‚ €,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861358/strange-characters-in-database-text-a-a-a/7889628#7889628) & [problem with special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881911/problem-with-special-characters/3882072#3882072)

Comment: Database charset is set to UTF-8. I have looked at the point where I pass the string to the database via a Java backend. The string at that point already contains bad characters. So the is issue prior to database entry.

Comment: How do you know the characters are already bad before going into the database?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel because when debugging the Java back-end I can see all incoming POST data. It is at that point I can see the string containing invalid characters (before it gets to the DB).

Comment: But it is correct when you directly output the POST data to the browser? Strange. Is there something wrong when the data goes from PHP to Java?

Comment: I suppose there's a possibility the Java may receive it incorrectly.

Comment: Can't you directly access your database from within PHP?

Comment: No, the system is setup in such a way that there is a Java API layer responsible for setting and getting data. Then there's a PHP layer which is responsible for the font-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue both sides of the pond. The issue PHP side which this question regards was that the data was being sent to the back-end via a GET request (url encoded). I have changed this to a POST request.

This has allowed me to specify the UTF-8 charset when sending the headers for the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
utf8_decode()
```

On the server side for the variables you're passing? PHP is likely expecting **iso-8859-1** rather than **uft-8**.

Comment: That appears to change the values to `?` characters.

Comment: Curious, just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616240/corrupted-characters-when-jquery-ajax-sends-to-php-utf-8-iso-8859-incompatibi) along the same lines.